# Strange scala array size

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an empty array, ret.size = 0, but using this to set size of a new array I'm getting array of size 1. No multi-threading involved.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0qgF.jpg)

Comment: New screen-shot, even more weird...
![Screenshot](http://imgur.com/UXDyRlu)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Especially not links to screenshots of code. Your first link is already dead and it's not even been half an hour.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're getting an `Array[Int]` with the single item. That item is equal to `roots.size` e.g. `0`.

`Array[Int](roots.size)` in your case is just another way of writing `Array(0)`. Compare that to the `List(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this issue is that **new ArrayInt** and **ArrayInt** are different constructors and behave differently.